# How can i delete all divs with a certain class name?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Using jquery, what is the best way to delete all divs with a certain class name ? (I don't want to just hide the div but fully delete it).  So if I have this code:

```
<div class="Test" ><div class="ABC" ><div class="Test" >
```

after I call this method where class = "Test", i would just see:

```
<div class="ABC" >
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
$("div.Test").remove();
```

That'll do it.

Comment: And if you know that there aren't other elements with Test class, `$('.Test').remove()` is trivially faster

Comment: how to get it back?

Comment: @manishkumar Sounds like you're needing something like jQuery's [`.detatch()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of `.remove()`.  detaching the node allows you to reattach it later.