# Remove next element after specific tag

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to make a "onclick" function to remove only the closer element of a specific tag!

For example:

```
<div>
    <video src="path/video.mp4"></video>
    <div>This div must be removed</div>
    <div>Controls</div>
</div>
```

In this situation, I must search for all tags "video" in the page and remove only the next div (with "this div must be removed"). And keep the div with "controls". So I must have this as result:

```
<div>
    <video src="path/video.mp4"></video>
    <div>Controls</div>
</div>
```

The way I'm doing, I lost everythig:

```
function remove() {

    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    for (var i=0;i<videos.length;i+=1){
          var classe = videos[i].getAttribute("class");

          parentDiv = videos[i].parentNode;
          var classParent = parentDiv.getAttribute("class");
          var arrayClassParent = classParent.split(' ');
          var classParent = arrayClassParent[0];
          var divVideo = document.getElementsByClassName(classParent)[0];

          var cntnt = document.getElementsByClassName(classParent)[i];
          while (cntnt.childNodes.length > 1) {
            cntnt.removeChild(cntnt.lastChild);
          }     
    }
}
```

Note: The div class and ID is set variable.. So I can call them using IDs and Classes...

Comment: Have you tried adding a class name to all the divs you want to remove then `$("div.Test").remove();`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i delete all divs with a certain class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048113/how-can-i-delete-all-divs-with-a-certain-class-name)

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("video")[i].parentNode.children[2].remove() or sth like this :)

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to remove the next div, even if it's not the next sibling, or the next sibling, even if it's not a div. Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the `nextElementSibling` field to access and remove the element directly after each `video` in your document? So something along the lines of this might work for you:

```js
function removeElementNextToVideo() {

  // Query for all video elements in document
  for(const video of document.body.querySelectorAll('video')) {

    // For each video, check for and remove the element directly 
    // after (next) to it
    if(video.nextElementSibling) {

        video.nextElementSibling.remove();
    }
  }
}

removeElementNextToVideo();
```

```html
<div>
  <video src="path/video.mp4"></video>
  <div>This div must be removed</div>
  <div>Controls</div>
</div>
```

Also, if you want to remove the next element only if it is a DIV you can do the following:

```js
function removeDivNextToVideo() {

  // Query for all video elements in document
  for(const video of document.body.querySelectorAll('video')) {

    // For each video, check for and remove the element directly 
    // after (next) to it only if the element is a DIV
    if(video.nextElementSibling && video.nextElementSibling.tagName === 'DIV') {

        video.nextElementSibling.remove();
    }
  }
}

removeDivNextToVideo();
```

```html
<div>
  <video src="path/video.mp4"></video>
  <h4>H4 directly after video, so nothing gets removed</h4>
  <div>This div must be removed</div>
  <div>Controls</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TinyGiant—it's not easy to spot, see [*Interface NodeList*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist), where it's defined as iterable. I really don't like the current "living standard" that doesn't tell you when features were introduced or the changes made between versions (which seem to be published almost daily).

Comment: @RobG thanks for that - I've updated the answer to inculde a solution for both cases

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can a selector with an [*Adjacent sibling combinator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `video + div` to select div elements that immediately follow a video element, e.g.

```js
function removeDivs() {
  document.querySelectorAll('video + div').forEach(div => div.parentNode.removeChild(div));
}
```

```css
video {height: 10px; border: 1px solid red;}
```

```html
<div>
    <video src="path/video.mp4"></video>
    <div>This div must be removed</div>
    <div>Controls</div>
</div>
<div>
    <video src="path/video.mp4"></video>
    <div>This div must be removed</div>
    <div>Controls</div>
</div>
<button onclick="removeDivs()">Remove divs</button>
```